# Theorem which states that for some function: "moving in the negative direction of the gradient" leads you to some (local) extremum point"?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, gradient-descent

I know this sounds like a very obvious and evident statement - but is there some theorem in math that formalizes the idea that "for some function, at a given point : "moving in the negative direction of the gradient" leads you to some (local) extremum point?" .

Recently, I read about the following theorem called "Fermat's Theorem on Stationery Points" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)) that proves "if the point (a,b) is a local extremum for some function "f", then the derivative of "f" at the point (a,b) is 0".

Is there some extension of this theorem that states (the obvious idea) ""moving in the negative direction of the gradient leads you to this (local) extremum point"? Or is this idea so basic and intuitive, there is no proof required?

Thanks

Comment: There are various convergence theorems for the gradient descent algorithm that you can find in optimization textbooks. Definitely a proof is required.

Comment: There may be no extremum. Take $f(x) = -x$ or $f(x) = e^{-x}$ for example.

Comment: thankyou for your reply! i am aware of these theorems that show the convergence of the gradient descent algorithm. however, i am more interested in "very general results from calculus that show that the gradient of the functions reduce as you continue in the direction of the extremum points". do you know of any such theorems? thanks

Comment: This is a consequence of a few things. The mean value theorem tells you that if your derivative is negative, you are decreasing, and the chain rule tells you that directional derivatives are the dot product of the gradient and the direction vector. The formula for dot product in terms of cosine then gives that the negative of the gradient is the direction of fastest decrease. But it isn’t a “theorem” to put these things together. Not every function has a local minimum, and even if there is a global minimum, it isn’t guaranteed to find any existing local minima. Convexity will make it work.

Comment: A full and general statement of the behavior of the gradient descent algorithm **is** a "very general result from calculus ..." of the kind you ask for. It needs some hypotheses, but they're no weaker than one can reasonably expect; and it has conclusions that are as strong as one can expect.

Comment: “very general results from calculus that show that the gradient of the functions reduce as you continue in the direction of the extremum points" Look closely at those convergence proofs in optimization textbooks; this is the type of thing that they show.